# Android Firebase create user task not show error but not working

Tags: android, firebase

I'm learning from youtube how to create user from firebase using android studio. I've follow the istruction correctly but I've got problem. The problem is, the .createUserWithEmailAndPassword syntax. It seems that the task for creating the user is not working but not show any error on log. I've did what suggestion provided on stackoverflow.com, but the problem still occur. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ahmadfaza.newfoodorderclient">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.ahmadfaza.newfoodorderclient.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter email"
        android:id="@+id/editEmail"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter password"
        android:id="@+id/editPass"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:onClick="signupButtonClicked"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Already have an account ?"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:onClick="signinButtonClicked"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ahmadfaza.newfoodorderclient;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText email,pass;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPass);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    }

    public void signupButtonClicked(View view)
    {
        final String email_text = email.getText().toString().trim();
        final String pass_text = pass.getText().toString().trim();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email_text) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass_text))
        {
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email_text,pass_text).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user = mDatabase.child(user_id);
                        current_user.child("Name").setValue(email_text);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: clean your project !

Comment: Have you tried to implement the `else` part of your `if statement` to log the error? Try to add this line inside the else part: `Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());` What is the message?

Comment: There i'snt "createUserWithEmail:failure" show on my apps log

Comment: Visit My Firebase Helper Class
https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Firebase-Helper/blob/master/app/src/main/java/inc/droidflick/firebasetutorial/firebasenetwork/FireBaseHelper.java